# Google Geocoding Response Issue - Returns 620 Error only in PHP Script

Tags: php, xml

I am attempting to set up a script that uses Google's Geocoding service. However, I have encountered a strange problem when making requests. Here is my simplified request:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&key=MY_API_KEY&q=1600+Pennsylvania+Avenue+Northwest+Washington+DC+20500");
print_r($xml);
?>
```

Here is the output from that code:

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Response] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Status] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [code] => 620 [request] => geocode ) ) )

It is returning the error code 620, which means I am making requests too rapidly. However, I am only making a single request and I have not even come close to my request limit. What is even more strange is that when I access the URL directly, it returns the XML response without any trouble at all. It is like there is some kind of firewall/permissions setting somewhere that is blocking the correct response from my PHP script. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you exceeded the daily limit time ? btw checkout if other guys are using your IP/APIkey, maybe they are exceeding the limit ...

Comment: Thank for the ideas, but I am definitely the only one working with this key. Besides, if that were the issue why does it work when I access it directly? I would think it would fail there as well.

Comment: Try it without your API key and see what you get ...

Comment: Have you tried loading it another way and just printing it? i.e. fopen or file_get_contents?

Comment: I don't know what's the PHP version you're using but according to the PHP MANUAL <<Libxml 2 unescapes the URI, so if you want to pass e.g. b&c as the URI parameter a, you have to call simplexml_load_file(rawurlencode('http://example.com/?a=' . urlencode('b&c'))). Since PHP 5.1.0 you don't need to do this because PHP will do it for you.>> So maybe you have to encode the url with rawurlencode(), or try it with file_get_contents() & SimpleXMLElement() ...

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV When I try it without the key I get the exact same results. It works fine when accessed directed but returns the same error code in my php script.

Comment: @jpiasetz Yes, I have tried those method but they don't return any results at all.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Also, we are using php 5.2. The code that I am using I copied and pasted straight from the Google developer page, so it shouldn't be an issue with how the request is being made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fyi, my final solution was to rewrite the script using Javascript and doing everything client side instead of server side. I'm still not quite sure what was wrong with the request I was making from my php script, but at least I accomplished what I needed. Thanks for all the suggestions!